# How to extract number between curly braces and 50 words before the curly braces in java?

Tags: java, regex

i have to extract the number between square braces and 50 words before the curly braces.

```
Input     I am very much new to java...[1] and i want to know....[1-2] more.   
          I am
          a student..[3]

output    [1]  I am very much new to java...
          [1-2] and i want to know...
          [3] I am a student...

    please help me.
```

Comment: (a) There are no curly braces here. I see only square brackets. (b) 50 what? (c) What happened to the `more.`? (d) What have you tried?

Comment: sorry its square brackets and i need to extract 50 words before the sqare brackets...more is just a word in  input...first i tired to extract sqare brackets in my file..using this pattern                                                    Matcher pat = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]").matcher(filename)... but my output was square brackets ->[] nothing else....

Comment: @KarthickMurugamoorthi What's your expected output?

Comment: ex Input-> file contains-> some words[1] like this[1-2] and need to extract[3]                                                                                             output->file             [1]      some words(50 words before the [1] square                                    bracket)                  [1-2]   some words,like this(50 words before[1-2])                                                                        [3]        and need to extract(50 words before [3])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds a lot like homework and I don't want to solve it for you. But here's the general idea:

1. With a regexp find all the `[bracket expressions]`.
2. Now that you know where each bracket expression is, you can also extract the text between each bracket expression and the previous one (or the start of the string, if it's the first bracket expression).
3. For each of these text strings, use a regexp to find all words (I assume that a "word" is a bunch of word-characters that are all together). This is again a very simple regexp.
4. Now that you know the locations of all the words in the text string, find the 50th from the end (or, if there aren't so many words, the first). Copy the part of the text that starts at this word and ends at the bracket expression.

Any questions? :)

Comment: thanks Vilx for your guidance...As i said in my question i'm very much new to java and i tried like this  Matcher pat = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]").matcher(filename);  but it returning only square braces[] not number

Comment: @KarthickMurugamoorthi - I don't know much about how Regexps work in Java, but the `?` seems to be unnecessary. Also, instead of matching `.`, why don't you try matching any character that **isn't** a closing square brakcet?

Comment: @KarthickMurugamoorthi - A quick google query gave me this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html Looks like a nice Java Regexp reference. Also, when working with regexps, it's useful to have a testing tool. Regexps can be tricky to get right, so you might want to experiment for a while. You can write your own, or use the many available on the web. Just be careful to use a Java one - Regexp syntaxes tend to have subtle differences between programming languages.

Comment: @KarthickMurugamoorthi - Also, one more tip - for every programming language there is an official documentation somewhere out there. Find it and remember it. It's your best friend. It contains the answers to many, many questions that you will have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex

```
((?:\w+\W*?){0,50}?)\[([\d-]+)\]
```

This captures the numbers in square brackets in capture group 2, and the text before that in capture group 1.

[regex101 demo.](https://regex101.com/r/hP4bE3/1)

---

```
(  // first capture group
    (?:
        \w+ // consume a sequence of word characters
        \W*? // and any following non-word characters, if any
    ){0,50}? // up to 50 words, as few as possible.
)
\[ // a square opening bracket
( // second capture group
    [\d-]+ // a sequence of digits and dashes
)
\] // a square closing bracket
```

Comment: Thanks :) for your regex.                                                   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filename = "C:\\conversion\\sample.txt";
        String line = null;
            FileReader fileReader =  new FileReader(filename);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader =  new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                
              if(line.matches("((?:\w+\W*?){0,50}?)\[([\d-]+)\]"))
                System.out.println(line);
      In regex it showing illegal escape character